# How do I create random teams of people, each person has multiple parameters, and the parameters are equally distributed among teams

Tags: algorithms, uniform-distribution, combinatorics

As the title suggests, I am trying to divide a group of people randomly into different teams of equal size. However, each person has parameters that go with them (such as age). If there is only one parameter, I understand that it is easy(ish) to equally distribute people based on that single parameter. However, if each person has two or more parameters (for example age and hair color), is there an algorithm for distributing these people randomly such that both parameters are distributed “as equally as possible” among the teams?

More theoretically, if I have *n* objects, each of them a *k-tuple* of integers, how do I distribute them into *m* groups such that we maximize the uniformity of each entry of the *k-tuple* together? Or rather, minimize the disparity between the group with the largest amount of objects with parameter *X* and the fewest amount of objects with parameter *X* for each parameter *X* of our *k-tuple*.

Comment: Fractional factorial experimental designs would be one approach. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_factorial_design

Answer (score 0):

This has been called "[anticlustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331804/is-there-an-opposite-to-clustering-or-anti-clustering)". Take a look at the R package `anticlust`. It supports mixtures of numeric and categorical variables.

Here is an example for 60 individuals with 2 numeric attributes and 2 categorical attributes.

```
m <- cbind(
  runif(60),
  rnorm(60),
  sample(2, 60, 1),
  sample(4, 60, 1)
)
```

Assign the individuals to 6 groups of 10.

```
grp <- anticlustering(m[,1:2], 6, categories = m[,3:4])
diversity_objective(m, grp)
#> [1] 582.5438
```

show the breakout of each attribute by group

```
lapply(3:4, \(i) table(grp, m[,i]))
#> [[1]]
#>    
#> grp 1 2
#>   1 4 6
#>   2 4 6
#>   3 4 6
#>   4 5 5
#>   5 5 5
#>   6 5 5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    
#> grp 1 2 3 4
#>   1 2 3 2 3
#>   2 3 3 2 2
#>   3 3 3 2 2
#>   4 3 3 2 2
#>   5 2 3 3 2
#>   6 2 2 3 3
plot_clusters(m[,1:2], grp)
```

Comment: I see! Upon further research on anti-clustering, it seems not optimal in reasonable time for my problem (as it is an NP-Hard problem). I am attempting to do 50 people, each with 2 parameters, and each parameter has 4 distinct possible values. I calculated the time it would take to run for me to be around 2 years.